# Multiple filters OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, winforms

At the moment I have three buttons on a form, each opens a different form (form2 with a textbox to display the text from the textfile, form3 with a picturebox to display the image)

What I am trying to do is put the two together for my last button so  the user can filter which type to open (TXT Files or Image files).  I am not sure how I can put the two together and get them to work.

The code I used to just open text files:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
            ofd.Filter = "TXT Files(*.txt;)|*.txt;";
            if(ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                using(StreamReader rdText = new StreamReader(ofd.FileName))
                {
                    string info = File.ReadAllText(ofd.FileName);
                    TextDocumentForm newTextDocument = new TextDocumentForm();
                    newTextDocument.TextFileName = info;
                    newTextDocument.Show();                 
                }
            }
        }
```

What I use to open my image files

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {          
                OpenFileDialog ofdi = new OpenFileDialog();
                ofdi.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
                ofdi.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.bmp)|*.jpg;*.jpeg;.bmp;";
                if (ofdi.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    Image image = Image.FromFile(ofdi.FileName);
                    ImgDoc newImageDoc = new ImgDocumentForm();
                    newImageDoc.ImageShow = image;
                    newImageDoc.Show();
                }            
        }
```

Any help is appreciated as I am trying to develop my understanding of how OpenFileDialog still works.

Comment: Just keep using the pipe separator: "TXT Files(*.txt;)|*.txt|Image Files(*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.bmp)|*.jpg;*.jpeg;.bmp"  I'm not sure that is what the question is about though.

Comment: The filters will show the file types that contain the extensions you specify. If you add both types (i.e., .txt & .jpg in the proper format) to the filter you'll see files of those types in the dialog. What to do is: when the user selects a file, you can query the extension and route it to the respective method to handle that type of file.

Comment: So far I am understanding the extension part but the bit I am confused with is how I can route each filter to do what I want (If the user decides to open a TXT File and selects it on the filters how would I go by making it do my streamreader bit, and vice versa?)

Comment: Use `Path.GetFileExtension(ofd.FileName)` to examine the file type selected by the user.  Your posted code isn't using the dialog's information, by the way.  openText and openImage aren't declared in your example.  Always post real code.

Comment: It was not my original code, I had some help getting the layout and was just trying to make some small demos for later reference in the future.  I was changing the names as I was getting confused, and was testing out a few changes.  My apologies, and thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combining filters:

```
var openFile = new OpenFileDialog
            {
                InitialDirectory = @"C:\",
                Filter = "TXT Files(*.txt;)|*.txt;|Image Files(*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.bmp)|*.jpg;*.jpeg;.bmp;"
            };
```

Then use `Path.GetExtension()` to see which route you should take:

```
if (openFile.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    var ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(openFile.FileName);
    if (ext == ".txt")
    {
        // Open text file
    }
    else if (ext == ".jpg" || ext == ".jpeg" || ext == ".bmp")
    {
        // Open image file
    }
}
```